# Testing my firebase auth function but somehow it always return null on repository call every time

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

[image]This is my repository code AuthRepository
Tried this simple function

```
  Future<UserCredential> signsInWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: "verificationId",
        smsCode: "smsCode",
      );
      return await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        message: 'Failed to sign in with phone number: $e',
        code: 'signInWithPhoneNumberError',
      );
    }
  }
```

Tried with FutureVoid

```
  FutureVoid signInWithPhoneNumber(
    BuildContext context,
    String phoneNumber,
  ) async {
    try {
      return right(
        await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) async {
            throw Exception('YAHA AARHI HAI ERROR --> ${error.message}');
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
            // Go to OTP screen when the SMS code is sent.
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                  child: OtpScreen(
                    verificationId: verificationId,
                    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                  )),
            );
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
        ),
      );
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.message!));
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }
```

I am using a controller in between AuthController

```
  void signInWithPhoneNumber(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    state = true;
    final res =
        await _authRepository.signInWithPhoneNumber(context, phoneNumber);
    state = false;

    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message, false),
      (r) => null, // Success
    );
  }
```

My firebase_test.dart

```
    test('signInWithPhoneNumber - success', () async {
      const fakePhoneNumber = "1234567890";
      final fakeUserCredential = MockUserCredential();

      when(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential))
          .thenReturn(Future.value(fakeUserCredential));

      final result =
          await authRepository.signsInWithPhoneNumber(fakePhoneNumber);
      expect(result, fakeUserCredential);
      verify(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)).called(1);
    });

//Also tried this 

  test('signInWithPhoneNumber', () async {
      const fakePhoneNumber = "1234567890";
      when(mockAuthRepository.signInWithPhoneNumber(
              mockBuildContext, fakePhoneNumber))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Future(() => right(null)));
      //Calling this function from controller
      authController.signInWithPhoneNumber(mockBuildContext, fakePhoneNumber);
      //Verify this in repository function call whether through controller call it got called or not
      verify(authController.signInWithPhoneNumber(
              mockBuildContext, fakePhoneNumber))
          .called(1);
      expect(authController.state, true);
    });
```

Should Test successfully but getting error

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

or for futureVoid function I get this error

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<Failure, void>>'

Comment: Please specify your error photo's to better understanding your error.

Comment: I have added screenshot of the error